# Finding the matrix of an orthogonal projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, vectors

**Find the matrix $A$ of the orthogonal projection onto the line $L$ in $\mathbb R^2$ that consists of all scalar multiples of the vector \begin{pmatrix}6\\ 5\end{pmatrix}**

So I have tried to find the various required basis and then turn them into the orthonormal basis, but I can't quite get the final matrix. I assume I am missing some steps.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- Find the image of $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ on the line $L$. Call it $A_1$
- Find the image of $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ on the line $L$. Call it $A_2$.
- Your desired matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} A_1 & A_2\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

The projection matrix $P$ giving the orthogonal projection onto a line is given by the outer product of a unit vector on that line. So in this case the line is given by the spanning set of the vector $\begin{pmatrix}6\\5\end{pmatrix}$, so we have
$$P=uu^T=\left(\frac{1}{\Vert v\Vert}v\right)\left(\frac{1}{\Vert v\Vert}v^T\right)$$
where $v=\begin{pmatrix}6\\5\end{pmatrix}$ and $u$ is the normalized version of $v$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall in vector calculus the projection of a vector $\mathbf{v}$ onto a vector $\mathbf{a}$ is given by
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Proj}_{\mathbf{a}} \mathbf{v} = \left(\frac{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{v}}{\mathbf{a}\cdot \mathbf{a}}\right) \mathbf{a}.
\end{align}
Define the mapping $T_\mathbf{a}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $T_\mathbf{a}\mathbf{v}= \operatorname{Proj}_{\mathbf{a}}\mathbf{v}$. Show that $T_\mathbf{a}$ is linear then find the matrix representation with respect to the standard basis $\mathcal{S}=\{\mathbf{e}_1, \mathbf{e}_2\}$ by
\begin{align}
[T_\mathbf{a}]_{\mathcal{S}}= A =\ ( [T_\mathbf{a} \mathbf{e}_1]_\mathcal{S}, [T_\mathbf{a} \mathbf{e}_2]_\mathcal{S})
\end{align}
where $[\mathbf{v}]_\mathcal{S}$ means to express the vector $\mathbf{v}$ in coordinate form with respect to the basis $\mathcal{S}$.